# Proof equivalence of $X\succcurlyeq Y \iff Y^{-1}\succcurlyeq X^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

For to symmetric matrices $X,Y$ I would like to prove this via Schur. However, I'm not fully understand the solution provided.

$$ X\succcurlyeq Y \iff X-Y\succcurlyeq 0 \iff \begin{pmatrix}X & 1\\1 & Y^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}\succcurlyeq 0\iff Y^{-1}-1X^{-1}1\succcurlyeq 0$$

The very last two $\iff$ are the ones which trouble me. How can we say
$$X-Y\succcurlyeq 0 \iff \begin{pmatrix}X & 1\\1 & Y^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}\succcurlyeq 0$$

and

$$\begin{pmatrix}X & 1\\1 & Y^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}\succcurlyeq 0\iff Y^{-1}-1X^{-1}1\succcurlyeq 0$$

Comment: How is the relation $\succcurlyeq$ defined?

Comment: @Math It means that the matrix $X$ is positive semi-definite if $X \succcurlyeq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Schur Conditions for positive definiteness and semi-definiteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Conditions_for_positive_definiteness_and_semi-definiteness) for a matrix

$$X=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\
B^T & C
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $A$ is invertible, we have
$$X \succcurlyeq 0 \iff A \succcurlyeq 0, X /A = C - B^T A^{-1} B \succcurlyeq 0.$$

Applied to the case of your question, this provides the equivalence you're looking for.

*Note: wikipedia provides a link about the equivalence I mention above.*

Comment: many thanks for your answer. May I also ask you about the following equivalence. I've updated my question:$ X-Y\succcurlyeq 0 \iff \begin{pmatrix}X & 1\\1 & Y^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}\succcurlyeq 0$